# How can I preserve a checkbox value type in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox

I am working in jsx / react and I'd like to preserve the value type of a checkbox.

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  name={name}
  value={value}
  checked={checked}
  disabled={disabled}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Presently If the value is e.g. a boolean or a number it get's converted to a string in the onChange handler's e.target.value handle. E.g. 'false' or '1'.

Is there a way to preserve the type, or is there a more idiomatic way to re-establish the type than `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`?

Comment: JavaScript is loosely typed. TypeScript might be able to do what you want.

Comment: To my understanding the same problem would exist in typescript. This is not  a developer typing error, this is boolean/number in, string out.

Comment: You're probably right. This is a pretty common issue. Are you running into a specific case where it's causing problems or are you just wondering about handling this situation in general?

Comment: I have a specific instance of a general problem, ideally handled in the most idiomatic way.

Comment: Specs say checkbox values must be text, so it looks like React is just running .toString() on any values to comply. Looks like special handling is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Best

HTML checkbox values (as with all attributes) must be text. This means that all non-string data must be serialized into a string. React uses .toString() by default.

I would conclude the most flexible, reversible, and idiomatic way is to use `JSON.stringify()` and then `JSON.parse()` to recover.

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  name={name}
  value={JSON.stringify(value)}
  checked={checked}
  disabled={disabled}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>

handleChange(e) {
  const value = JSON.parse(e.target.value)
}
```

### Alternative / Manual

Fred's (unedited original) option works if you only need booleans and number values.

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  name={name}
  value={value}
  data-type={typeof value}
  checked={checked}
  disabled={disabled}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>

handleChange(e) {
  const type = e.target.getAttribute('data-type')) 
  const { value: stringValue } = e.target  
  switch(type) {
    case 'number': {
    }
    case 'boolean': {
    }
    default: {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down but this helped me and should actually be the accepted answer.

Comment: From memory another user got upset and downvoted everything because I felt their answer (now deleted) missed the point. Feel free to upvote the question too. Glad it helped :).

Answer (score 0):

Hi dev check this preserve value in checkbox

```
            <Col sm={6}>
              <FormGroup check inline>
                <CustomInput type="radio" id="IsPaymentKind" label="Payment Kind"
                  value="Payment Kind"
                  checked={this.state.voucher_kind === 'Payment Kind'}
                  onChange={event => {
                    this.setState({ voucher_kind: event.target.value });
                  }}
                />
              </FormGroup>

              <FormGroup check inline>
                <CustomInput type="radio" id="IsReceiptKind" label="Receipt Kind"
                  value="Receipt Kind"
                  checked={this.state.voucher_kind === 'Receipt Kind'}
                  onChange={event => {
                    this.setState({ voucher_kind: event.target.value });
                  }} />
              </FormGroup>

              <FormGroup check inline>
                <CustomInput type="radio" id="Other" label="Other"
                  value="Other" checked={this.state.voucher_kind === 'Other'}
                  onChange={event => {
                    this.setState({ voucher_kind: event.target.value });
                  }} />
              </FormGroup>

            </Col>
```

Comment: Also if that post helps. It does not really give much info about it. Please write what actually was wrong and what you added.

Comment: Your example shows how to calculate the boolean value of "checked". This question was instead about working the serialization of the value of a checkbox in jsx/html.